# Snowflake unloading beaks file into too many small files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I set it up to copy into multiple csv files with single=false just in case the size of the file gets too big. But now even with the much smaller size of the file (5KB), it still breaks into several files. (I believe the default size is 16M, which I didn't change.) Can someone explain why it's like that? Is there a way we can set it not to break into multiple files if the file size is really not that big?

Answer (score 2):

By setting that parameter, you are telling Snowflake to take advantage of parallel processing (multiple files) to make the copy as performant as possible.  This all happens automatically with SINGLE=FALSE and there is no conditional parameter to activate this (it's either true or false for whether you want a single file or multiple files).

Some best practices and options are here as well:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Best-Practices-for-Data-Unloading